# Extend Array class by adding new method to global interface

Tags: arrays, typescript, declaration

I am trying to add a new method (`last`) to the `Array` class.

This is what I'm doing (amoung other functions declared) in my `test.ts` file:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        last(): T;
    }
}

if (!Array.prototype.last) {
    Array.prototype.last = function <T>(): T {
        return this[this.length - 1];
    }
}
```

However this does not work as it seems to completely erase the other definitions for `Array` so now I get errors like:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This happens if I try to access the `length` property of any arrays.

How do I properly achieve this? Does the declaration have to go into a file by itself?

Comment: Are you using a module system? That is, do you use `import`/`export`?

Comment: @NitzanTomer No I simply have this declaration in the same file that I am using it in. IntelliJ does not show any errors, but once I compile it I get the errors

Comment: @NitzanTomer, Actually I do have some imports at the top of the file. Does this change anything?

Comment: If you are using imports/exports then you do need to augment the global. I see that the error you're getting is `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, it seems that the compiler thinks that your array doesn't exist at all. Can you add the code which generates this error?

Comment: @NitzanTomer, I was just about to post the code when I realised it was all my fault. I was indeed using an undefined array which is why I was getting the error. I believe this is the problem because it now seems to accept the code without any errors. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to augment the global module when you are importing/exporting.

Because this is not your case, you just need to do this:

```
interface Array<T> {
    last(): T;
}
```

That is, don't wrap it with `declare global { ... }`.

Also, in the actual implementation, there's no need for generics, it can/should be:

```
if (!Array.prototype.last) {
    Array.prototype.last = function(): any {
        return this[this.length - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am now getting the following errors: `Property 'last' does not exist on type 'string[]'` and `Property 'last' does not exist on type 'any[]'`

Comment: The error is on anywhere I have `Array.prototype.last` and basically anywhere else I have used `someArray.last()`